# How can I reduce the time complexity of the following loop?

Tags: c, math, time-complexity, modulo

```
for(i=0;i<N-2;i++)
       count=(count*10)%M;
```

Here, N can be upto 10^18 and M is (10^9 +7). Since this loop takes O(n) time to execute, I get TLE in my code. Any way to reduce the time complexity?

Comment: This is still a programming question (not off-topic in my opinion) but help  you will find in math.

Comment: what is the initial value of count? Here M is constant i...N is also known. Now the whole things depend on the initial value of count.

Comment: @ruhul initial value of count is a one digit integer. N is a variable 2<=N<=10^18

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Efficient_computation_with_integer_exponents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is basically:

> (count*a^b)%mod = ((count%mod)*((a^b)%mod))%mod

a = 10, b = 10^18

You can find ((a^b)%mod) using:

```
long long power(long long x, long long y, long long p)
{
    long long res = 1;      // Initialize result

    x = x % p;  // Update x if it is more than or 
                // equal to p

    while (y > 0)
    {
        // If y is odd, multiply x with result
        if (y & 1)
            res = (res*x) % p;

        // y must be even now
        y = y>>1; // y = y/2
        x = (x*x) % p;  
    }
    return res;
}
```

Time Complexity of the power function is O(log y).

In your case count is a 1-digit number so we can simply multiply this with (count%mod), and finally take mod of the result. If count is a big number too, and can cause overflow then we can do:

```
long long mulmod(long long a, long long b, long long mod)
{
    long long res = 0; // Initialize result
    a = a % mod;
    while (b > 0)
    {
        // If b is odd, add 'a' to result
        if (b % 2 == 1)
            res = (res + a) % mod;

        // Multiply 'a' with 2
        a = (a * 2) % mod;

        // Divide b by 2
        b /= 2;
    }

    // Return result
    return res % mod;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971888/modular-multiplication-of-large-numbers-in-c?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: To multiply a\*b, first calculate a\*b/2 then add it twice. For calculating a\*b/2 calculate a*b/4 and so on. That is why. I use this in online coding, so it is correct and verified a lot of times.

Comment: The original problem calculates "x * 10^(N-1) % M". Since N could be very large, say 10^18, b in "((a^b)%mod)" could be as large as 10^(10^18-1), which can't be saved by a `long long` int.

Comment: That's why I wrote power function.

Comment: Yeah!!!!!!!!!!! For multiplication in case count is also a large number.

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri Sorry just not patient enough to read the details :P maybe neither do other people ...

Comment: No problem, hope you understood finally :)

Comment: `Any way to reduce the time complexity?` does your answer, answer this question? O(n) to O(1) ?

Comment: It has reduced it to O(log n). Have mentioned it in the answer. See that.

Comment: e.g. - a^2 = (a^(2/2))*(a^(2/2)) but a^3 = a*(a^(2/2))*(a^(2/2))

Comment: @UtkarshPandey He has implemented the fast exponentiation algorithm described in the page linked by Oliver Charlesworth: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Efficient_computation_with_integer_exponents